# Is there any way to get microphone input on Android using Python?

Tags: python, android, pyaudio

I want to make an App using `kivy` and `speechrecognition`, so i ineed to get mic input. `PyAudio` doesn't support Android, and I have tried using `audiostream`, but that also doesn't seem to work. Can I somehow get audio input using Python on an Android device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Kivy to write Android apps in Python.

Android provides an audio interface described [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediarecorder#java) for Java/Kotlin.

The directions of how to wrap Android Java APIs using Pyjinius in Kivy is [here](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/android.html#:%7E:text=Plyer%20README.-,Pyjnius%C2%B6,-Pyjnius%20is%20a).

You also could also use Plyer. As documented [here](https://plyer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#plyer.facades.Audio=) the code would look something like:

```py
from plyer.facades import Audio

Audio.start() # starts recording

Audio.stop() # stops recording

Audio.play() # plays recording
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`sl4a`](https://github.com/damonkohler/sl4a) for getting the input

```
import sl4a
droid = sl4a.Android()
def listen():
   global result,error
   time.sleep(1)
   return droid.recognizeSpeech("Speak",None,None)[1]
```

Comment: Note on the site you linked: `" this probject is no longer under active development"`